# Custom Dialog fails "still" in Android 2.3.3 but not in 2.2 and 4.0.3 (using compability package v4)

Tags: android, xml, dialog

ive asked before but not getting any clearance...

I have upgraded my app to the standards of Android 4.0, and added the compability package v4 to still make it work for older devices.
The result, somehow, the Custom Dialog-boxes are instant 1-lines in 2.3, but not in 2.2 or 4.0.
Showing some images.
[image: Here is app with 4.0 and compatibility package]

[image: Heres app BEFORE 4.0 and BEFORE compatibility]

And the XML-file for the dialog is... well pretty basic imho

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            style="@style/DialogText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:autoLink="phone|web|email"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
            android:text="@string/about_text_big"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="14.0sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Please, help me here, obviously there is no problem in the code? Or is it "fundamental"? :S